# How do I successfully run JavaCV code example (JavaFxPlayVideoAndAudio.java)

Tags: java

I have an issue with running JavaCV/JavaFX example: [JavaFxPlayVideoAndAudio.java](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/JavaFxPlayVideoAndAudio.java). I cannot make it working. I got an error messages as listed bellow:

```
gru 04, 2021 1:14:27 PM mower.Demo$1 run
SEVERE: null
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1310)
    at mower/mower.Demo$1.run(Demo.java:87)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

I run it from Eclipse as Maven JavaFX project and from standalone Maven project - got the same errors.

Could you please advice what might be the problem?

Many thanks for your help and time.

Comment: I think it tries to get the first parameter from the application but the example does not check if there is any parameter at all. Try to call the program with some arguments.

Comment: I think you need to pass `videoFileName` as a first parameter. Use an absolute path to be sure.

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. If the problem is solved, accepting the solution would be appreciated. Be well!

Comment: Sure, but how can I do this? I do not see a 'check mark' to do this...

Comment: oh, sorry. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program tries to get the value of the first parameter but it does not check if the latter is provided.

You need to call the program with a `videoFileName` as a first parameter.